# Replace specific words in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

what is the best way to get and replace specific words in string  ?
for example I have

```
NSString * currentString = @"one {two}, thing {thing} good";
```

now I need find each {currentWord}

and apply function for it

```
 [self replaceWord:currentWord]
```

then replace currentWord with result from function

```
-(NSString*)replaceWord:(NSString*)currentWord;
```

Comment: do you want to replace each word within { and }?

Comment: depends on what word is in {}
so I need find {word} then cut the word from it, replace it then put it back somehow

Comment: Your question in incomplete. plz explain what you exactly want. what pattern you wnat to look for etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example shows how you can use `NSRegularExpression` and `enumerateMatchesInString` to accomplish the task. I have just used `uppercaseString` as function that replaces a word, but you can use your `replaceWord` method as well:

**EDIT:** The first version of my answer did not work correctly if the replaced words are
shorter or longer as the original words (thanks to Fabian Kreiser for noting that!) .
Now it should work correctly in all cases.

```
NSString *currentString = @"one {two}, thing {thing} good";

// Regular expression to find "word characters" enclosed by {...}:
NSRegularExpression *regex;
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{(\\w+)\\}"
                                                  options:0
                                                    error:NULL];

NSMutableString *modifiedString = [currentString mutableCopy];
__block int offset = 0;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:currentString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         // range = location of the regex capture group "(\\w+)" in currentString:
                         NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
                         // Adjust location for modifiedString:
                         range.location += offset;

                         // Get old word:
                         NSString *oldWord = [modifiedString substringWithRange:range];

                         // Compute new word:
                         // In your case, that would be
                         // NSString *newWord = [self replaceWord:oldWord];
                         NSString *newWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--- %@ ---", [oldWord uppercaseString] ];

                         // Replace new word in modifiedString:
                         [modifiedString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:newWord];
                         // Update offset:
                         offset += [newWord length] - [oldWord length];
                     }
 ];


NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

*Output:*

```
one {--- TWO ---}, thing {--- THING ---} good
```

Comment: The code doesn't work when the replacement word is shorter or longer than the original word, though.

Comment: @FabianKreiser: Ooops, you might be right. Actually I has a more complicated method that I tried to simplify by using `NSEnumerationReverse`, but it seems that this option does not work here. I will check that and update the answer - Thank you!

Comment: @FabianKreiser: I have updated the answer, it should work now. Thanks again!