# Replace specific words in html string

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I have dynamic string that currentString. 
For example currentstring like :

```
<html><head><title></title><meta content="width=320.000000, initial-scale=0.47, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" name="viewport"></head><body><table width="510" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top"><p><a href="http://erhandemirci.blogspot.com/masak-in-baskani-neden-gorevden-alindi-haberi-828402.html"><img src="http://erhandemirci.blogspot.com/images//news/r-farukeliedioglu-300200-828402.jpg" width="72" height="48" style="border: 1px #000000 solid;" hspace="2" align="left"></a>content...........</p> <p> </p> </td></tr></table></body></html>
```

I want to change table tag's width from 510  to 0. I tried following code but it's not working .

```
NSString *currentString = @"<html><...width > <table width="" .... > dynamic string";

    // Regular expression to find "word characters" enclosed by {...}:
    NSRegularExpression *regex;
    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\table width=\"(\\w+)\\\""
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:NULL];

    NSMutableString *modifiedString = [currentString mutableCopy];
    __block int offset = 0;
    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:currentString
                            options:0
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentString length])
                         usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                             // range = location of the regex capture group "(\\w+)" in currentString:
                             NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
                             // Adjust location for modifiedString:
                             range.location += offset;

                             // Get old word:
                             NSString *oldWord = [modifiedString substringWithRange:range];

                             // Compute new word:
                             // In your case, that would be
                             // NSString *newWord = [self replaceWord:oldWord];
                             NSString *newWord =@"0";

                             // Replace new word in modifiedString:
                             [modifiedString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:newWord];
                             // Update offset:
                             offset += [newWord length] - [oldWord length];
                         }
     ];


    NSLog(@"modified%@", modifiedString);
```

Comment: That code looks familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997712/replace-specific-words-in-nsstring/15997802#15997802 :-)

Comment: Yea I looked from here .But it's not working for me .Can you give me advice.What is wrong in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it almost right, only that `@"\\table ...` should be `@"\\<table ...`
in the pattern:

```
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\<table width=\"(\\w+)\\\""
                                                  options:0
                                                    error:NULL];
```

This would replace `<table width="NNN"` by `<table width="0"` for arbitrary `NNN`.

Note that generally it is not recommended to parse HTML with regular expressions.
Using a dedicated HTML parser might be the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know RegEx. I would solve this with `NSMutableString` methods like `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`